# Reading LeakCanary Log

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have installed LeakCanary to see if my app had memory leaks.

It appears so, but I can't read the log, any one can tell me how, or give the good tutorial I can't find???

In the doc in [github](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), it says:

> Once you have the leak trace, figure out which reference in the path should not exist. Then figure out why that reference still exists.

But I don't know how to do it.

Tx!

Here is my log.

```
In com.myapp.mobile:1.3:33.
* LEAK CAN BE IGNORED.
* com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen has leaked:
* GC ROOT static android.view.ViewConfiguration.
* references android.util.SparseArray.mValues
* references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
* references android.view.ViewConfiguration.mContext
* leaks com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen instance
[ 07-17 14:59:07.213 32231:  770 D/LeakCanary ]

* Device: samsung samsung SGH-I337M jflteub
* Android Version: 4.4.2 API: 19 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
* Durations: watch=5014ms, gc=155ms, heap dump=1322ms, 
[ 07-17 14:59:07.213 32231:  770 D/LeakCanary ]

* Class android.view.ViewConfiguration
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [
|   static DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 500
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_MIN_TIME = 40
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_SLOP = 100
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT = 300
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_TOUCH_SLOP = 8
|   static EDGE_SLOP = 12
|   static FADING_EDGE_LENGTH = 12
|   static GLOBAL_ACTIONS_KEY_TIMEOUT = 500
|   static HOVER_TAP_SLOP = 20
|   static HOVER_TAP_TIMEOUT = 150
|   static JUMP_TAP_TIMEOUT = 500
|   static KEY_REPEAT_DELAY = 50
|   static MAXIMUM_DRAWING_CACHE_SIZE = 1536000
|   static MAXIMUM_FLING_VELOCITY = 8000
|   static MINIMUM_FLING_VELOCITY = 50
|   static OVERFLING_DISTANCE = 6
|   static OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 0
|   static PAGING_TOUCH_SLOP = 16
|   static PRESSED_STATE_DURATION = 64
|   static SCROLL_BAR_DEFAULT_DELAY = 300
|   static SCROLL_BAR_FADE_DURATION = 250
|   static SCROLL_BAR_SIZE = 10
|   static SCROLL_FRICTION = 0.015
|   static 
|   static TAP_TIMEOUT = 180
|   static TOUCH_SLOP = 8
|   static WINDOW_TOUCH_SLOP = 16
|   static ZOOM_CONTROLS_TIMEOUT = 3000
|   static sConfigurations = android.util.SparseArray [
* Instance of android.util.SparseArray
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [
|   static DELETED = java.lang.Object [id=0x41884b48]
|   mValues = java.lang.Object[] [id=0x421af900;length=5
|   mKeys = int[] [id=0x421af8d8;length=5;size=32]
|   mSize = 1
|   mGarbage = false
* Array of java.lang.Object[]
|   [0] = android.view.ViewConfiguration [id=0x42a8a2d8]
|   [1] = null
|   [2] = null
|   [3] = null
|   [4] = null
* Instance of android.view.ViewConfiguration
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [
|   static DEFAULT_LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 500
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_MIN_TIME = 40
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_SLOP = 100
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT = 300
|   static DOUBLE_TAP_TOUCH_SLOP = 8
|   static EDGE_SLOP = 12
|   static FADING_EDGE_LENGTH = 12
|   static GLOBAL_ACTIONS_KEY_TIMEOUT = 500
|   static HOVER_TAP_SLOP = 20
|   static HOVER_TAP_TIMEOUT = 150
|   static JUMP_TAP_TIMEOUT = 500
|   static KEY_REPEAT_DELAY = 50
|   static MAXIMUM_DRAWING_CACHE_SIZE = 1536000
|   static MAXIMUM_FLING_VELOCITY = 8000
|   static MINIMUM_FLING_VELOCITY = 50
|   static OVERFLING_DISTANCE = 6
|   static OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 0
|   static PAGING_TOUCH_SLOP = 16
|   static PRESSED_STATE_DURATION = 64
|   static SCROLL_BAR_DEFAULT_DELAY = 300
|   static SCROLL_BAR_FADE_DURATION = 250
|   static SCROLL_BAR_SIZE = 10
|   static SCROLL_FRICTION = 0.015
|   static 
|   static TAP_TIMEOUT = 180
|   static TOUCH_SLOP = 8
|   static WINDOW_TOUCH_SLOP = 16
|   static ZOOM_CONTROLS_TIMEOUT = 3000
|   static sConfigurations = android.util.SparseArray [
|   mContext = com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen [
|   mDoubleTapSlop = 300
|   mDoubleTapTouchSlop = 48
|   mEdgeSlop = 36
|   mFadingEdgeLength = 36
|   mFadingMarqueeEnabled = false
|   mMaximumDrawingCacheSize = 8294400
|   mMaximumFlingVelocity = 24000
|   mMinimumFlingVelocity = 150
|   mOverflingDistance = 18
|   mOverscrollDistance = 0
|   mPagingTouchSlop = 96
|   mScrollbarSize = 30
|   mTouchSlop = 48
|   mWindowTouchSlop = 48
|   sHasPermanentMenuKey = true
|   sHasPermanentMenuKeySet = true
* Instance of com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen
|   ctx = com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen [id=0x42a7c450]
|   prefs = android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl [
|   mActionBar = null
|   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo [
|   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap [
|   mApplication = com.myapp.mobile.MyApplication [
|   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl [
|   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.
|   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread [id=0x4180aea0]
|   mTranslucentCallback = null
|   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName [
|   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy [id=0x42a03820]
|   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1 [id=0x42a7c5c8]
|   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration [
|   mDecor = null
|   mTitle = java.lang.String [id=0x42a85570]
|   mDefaultKeySsb = null
|   mSearchManager = null
|   mResultData = null
|   mEmbeddedID = null
|   mParent = null
|   mMenuInflater = null
|   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl [
|   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x42a7c670]
|   mManagedDialogs = null
|   mInstanceTracker = android.os.
|   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation [
|   mIntent = android.content.Intent [id=0x42a03568]
|   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
|   mLoaderManager = null
|   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList [id=0x42a7c5d8
|   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread [
|   mLoadersStarted = false
|   mIdent = 1123061480
|   mFinished = true
|   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
|   mResultCode = 0
|   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
|   mResumed = false
|   mDestroyed = true
|   mStartedActivity = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mTemporaryPause = false
|   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
|   mTitleColor = 0
|   mTitleReady = true
|   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
|   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
|   mChangingConfigurations = false
|   mVisibleFromClient = true
|   mVisibleFromServer = false
|   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
|   mWindowAdded = true
|   mCalled = true
|   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl [id=0x42a7c690]
|   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.impl.
|   mOverrideConfiguration = null
|   mResources = android.content.res.Resources [
|   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme [
|   mThemeResource = 2131296377
|   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl [id=0x42a7c690]

In com.myapp.mobile:1.3:33.
* com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs has leaked:
* GC ROOT static com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs.ctx
* leaks com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs instance
[ 07-17 15:00:10.945 32231: 1926 D/LeakCanary ]

* Device: samsung samsung SGH-I337M jflteub
* Android Version: 4.4.2 API: 19 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
* Durations: watch=5015ms, gc=218ms, heap dump=1071ms, 
[ 07-17 15:00:10.945 32231: 1926 D/LeakCanary ]

* Class com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [
|   static ENCUESTA = 5
|   static METRICA_DATOS = 0
|   static METRICA_ENCUESTAS = 1
|   static TEN_SECONDS = 10000
|   static ctx = com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs [
|   static errorList = java.util.ArrayList [
|   static idCaptura = 4
|   static idEncuesta = 0
|   static imageFileUri = null
|   static lMetricas = java.util.ArrayList [
|   static listLV = null
|   static rclForm = android.support.v7.widget.
|   static transparentEt = android.support.v7.widget.
* Instance of com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [
|   static ENCUESTA = 5
|   static METRICA_DATOS = 0
|   static METRICA_ENCUESTAS = 1
|   static TEN_SECONDS = 10000
|   static ctx = com.myapp.mobile.MetricaTabs [
|   static errorList = java.util.ArrayList [
|   static idCaptura = 4
|   static idEncuesta = 0
|   static imageFileUri = null
|   static lMetricas = java.util.ArrayList [
|   static listLV = null
|   static rclForm = android.support.v7.widget.
|   static transparentEt = android.support.v7.widget.
|   ab = android.support.v7.internal.app.
|   adbForm = null
|   eh = com.myapp.mobile.sqlite.EncuestaHandler [
|   tabLayout = android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
|   loc = null
|   mCaptura = null
|   mEncuesta = null
|   mSectionsPagerAdapter = com.myapp.mobile.
|   mViewPager = android.support.v4.view.ViewPager [
|   metrica = null
|   prefs = android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl [
|   numTab = 0
|   saveAndNew = false
|   encuesta = 0
|   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.
|   mAllLoaderManagers = android.support.v4.util.
|   mLoaderManager = null
|   mContainer = android.support.v4.app.
|   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.
|   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.
|   mCreated = true
|   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
|   mLoadersStarted = false
|   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
|   mReallyStopped = true
|   mResumed = false
|   mRetaining = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mActionBar = null
|   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo [
|   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap [
|   mApplication = com.myapp.mobile.MyApplication [
|   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl [
|   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.
|   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread [id=0x4180aea0]
|   mTranslucentCallback = null
|   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName [
|   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy [id=0x42f18c40]
|   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1 [id=0x42a92978]
|   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration [
|   mDecor = null
|   mTitle = java.lang.String [id=0x42fb8850]
|   mDefaultKeySsb = null
|   mSearchManager = null
|   mResultData = null
|   mEmbeddedID = null
|   mParent = null
|   mMenuInflater = null
|   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl [
|   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x429fd658]
|   mManagedDialogs = null
|   mInstanceTracker = android.os.
|   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation [
|   mIntent = android.content.Intent [id=0x42f2ded8]
|   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
|   mLoaderManager = null
|   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList [id=0x42a145a8
|   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread [
|   mLoadersStarted = false
|   mIdent = 1136727720
|   mFinished = true
|   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
|   mResultCode = 0
|   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
|   mResumed = false
|   mDestroyed = true
|   mStartedActivity = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mTemporaryPause = false
|   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
|   mTitleColor = 0
|   mTitleReady = true
|   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
|   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
|   mChangingConfigurations = false
|   mVisibleFromClient = true
|   mVisibleFromServer = true
|   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
|   mWindowAdded = true
|   mCalled = true
|   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl [id=0x429f95b0]
|   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.impl.
|   mOverrideConfiguration = null
|   mResources = android.content.res.Resources [
|   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme [
|   mThemeResource = 2131296377
|   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl [id=0x429f95b0]
```

Comment: Well, it says right there "com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen has leaked". There are several reasons it can happen as it says on LeakCanary readme file. It's hard to help you if you don't show the code that uses `com.myapp.mobile.SplashScreen`.

Comment: but my code is big!!! I will have to review all my code????

Comment: uyyy... not so great. So that lib is not so great... it just say "You have a problem", but doesn't say where, it just gives you Activity name :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This library is pure awesomeness and saved me a lot of headache. In many cases it shows exactly where the leak is. But in your case the leak occurs on your activity class itself so LeakCanary tells you from which class. You're probably registering the activity as a listener to another class and forget to unregister it. My advice is that you search in your activity class references to `this`. Each one of those can be a potential leak.

Comment: Yep, in that case, I had problems with Context --> http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html